# Using gRPC IServerStreamWriter without depending on Grpc.Core.Api

Tags: c#, grpc

Disclaimer: this may be a purely aesthetic problem.

I'm writing a backend which mostly uses gRPC to communicate with the outside world. Internally, most of the real work is done by an actor system. A design goal is to keep the actor system as free of outside dependencies as possible. This is achieved by providing services - in the gRPC case, there's a service which translates the gRPC calls and their data types into calls to the actor system and its data types. For example for each gRPC message, there is an equivalent actor system message, and all the gRPC service does is to copy gRPC to actor system messages and then pass that to some actor.

gRPC server subscripiton now makes me wonder. In protobuf it's defined as "stream", the resulting generated gRPC type contains a field of type IServerStreamWriter. How can I assign this IServerStreamWriter to something which doesn't depend on Grpc.Core.Api? It seems possible to define some stream type on the actor side and then have some copying take place, but I don't like the performance hit.

Comment: What do you mean by ```assign this IServerStreamWriter to something which doesn't depend on Grpc.Core.Api?```. Do you want use something like ```IServerStreamWriter<Banana>``` where Banana is not a message from gRPC??

Comment: IServerStreamWriter is also defined in Grpc.Core.Api, so that wouldn't solve my problem. I would like to define IBananaWriter<Banana> where both the writer and the message don't depend on gRPC, but which is assignment compatible to gRPC writer (if that makes sense..)

Comment: Idk if this makes sense for your problem and resolve your problem (because I don't have much knowledge in the area) but I think that you want to do services (in the part outside the gRPC project) that use messages coming from gRPC correct? It's just that I don't know if it works by injecting dependencies and then getting the address of the gRPC project to link things together but this is the only idea I see in my head, so it's an X for me in terms of helping you with the problem better, sry